# Move the Data Column To the Extreme Right

Tags: .net

I have a datatable.Three Columns are bound from the database, third Column is the TOTAL column.The other columns are generated at runtime.I want to move the TOTAL column which is the 3rd column to the extreme right.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
DataTable.Columns["Column_Name"].SetOrdinal(New_Index);
```